# What is this IIFE called?

Tags: javascript, iife

I can reason about this IIFE without issue, but as a new learner I have no idea what this pattern is called. Is there a name for this pattern? I've seen it quite a few times, but every time I try to search for further examples of it I'm at a loss of what to search for. Thanks!

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var foo = (function() {
    function bar() {
      return "bar";
    }
    return {
      bar: bar
    }
  }());
  console.log(foo.bar());
}());
```

Comment: I've seen "use strict" being used in angularJS, that's just off the top of my head though! Where did you obtain this code?

Comment: It's just one IIFE nested into another IIFE. Nothing fancy.

Comment: are you referring to an anonymous function -  a function without a name?

Comment: @Chris It's not only AngularJS or X library/framework that uses "use strict".

Comment: The pattern inside the main IIFE is called revealing module pattern, it is used to simply define all of module functions and variables in the private scope and return an anonymous object with pointers to the private functionality we wished to reveal as public. Please refer to http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: @Vohuman yeah, I'd have guessed that. I just thought i'd give it a shot.

Comment: In your example, I would call it "pretty useless".

Comment: @zerkms: Nothing common indeed, but rather something quite odd.

Comment: If you ask me, it's a mess.  It is way, way more complicated than need be to express the functionality offered.  Good code is no more complicated than need be to accomplish its goal.  Something much simpler will accomplish the same goal.  I don't think the whole structure you show has a particular name other than "overly complicated double IIFE".

Comment: to me, this feels like code  generated by TypeScript or Babel.  It's unfortunately common for someone to write a library in TypeScript, compile the JS, then publish only the JS as the consumable library.  Others pick up this library from GitHub or such, and try to replicate it in handwritten JavaScript, but never really understanding the reason for this complexity.

Comment: @Claies - that's my guess too - that this was generated by some code generator that uses the most general form of defining something so it has places to put multiple levels of private variables even when those features are not being used.  IMO, one would not hand write code this way.

Comment: Thanks for the input, everyone. I guess the challenge of being fairly new at this is trying to separate the overly complicated and contrived patterns from the succinct and useful ones. I've seen this pattern at least 10 times in the last few months, and was always perplexed by the reasoning behind it. I get the point of defining in a private scope and exposing in a public way that points to the private-- but I never understood the underlying meaning of doing it this way. So I thought I would replicate it and ask. Any examples of doing this by hand? Just curious to see how you would do it.